# Disabling option buttons based upon results of prior option buttons: Excel

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, nested-if

I am working on a project that requires me to disable certain option buttons in excel 2010 based on the results of prior option buttons. Some criteria will need multiple if statements, similar to a nested if. Some info; cell B107 in my example reflects which of the 5 option buttons they might have chosen. I have tried the following code but I have not been able to find success. Additionally, how would I make the disabled option button appear grey.

```
Private Sub OptionButton22_Change()
If Range ("B108") = 1 Then
OptionButton22.Enabled = False
Else
OptionButton22.Enabled = True
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: When it's not set to `Enabled` it will be grey.  You should probably qualify your `Range` object with a worksheets reference so it's clear which sheet this should be affected by.  Also, this code will only fire on changing `optionbutton22` - maybe you would be better off putting that code into the `Worksheet_Change` event instead and then check `Target.Value` where `Target.Address` = "$B$108"?